# List all the values stored in another model in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-admin

I have a small project that I need to create a system to record what a person has done each day during several time slots (e.g., "8:00-9:00", "10:00-11:00", "13:00-14:00"). I implemented the project in Django and use Django Admin to present the system.

I created three models tmpDate, tmpHour, tmpDateHour in models.py.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date as datetimeDate  

class tmpDate(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    total_tmp_time=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=1,default=0.0)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date

class tmpHour(models.Model):
    start_time=models.TimeField()
    end_time=models.TimeField()


    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.create_time)+"-"+str(self.update_time)


class tmpDateHour(models.Model):
    date=models.ForeignKey(tmpDate,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    hour_time=models.ForeignKey(tmpHour,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    tmp_length=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=1,default=0.0)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The idea is that I create some timeslots in tmpHour (e.g., "8:00-9:00", "10:00-11:00", "13:00-14:00"). Once I create a new Date in the Admin of tmpDate, then all the time slots stored in tmpHour will populate the respective fields. Something like this

[image: Expected]

However, I do not know how to do the setup in admin, I have the following setup in admin.py currently,

```
class tmpDateHourInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = tmpDateHour
    extra = 1

class tmpHourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class tmpDateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[tmpDateHourInline]

admin.site.register(tmpDate,tmpDateAdmin)
admin.site.register(tmpHour,tmpHourAdmin)
```

Which gives me the following result. It requires me to manually select the time slots.

[image: Currently]

How can I modify admin.py to make all the time slots in tmpHour automatically pop up and fill the fields?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this (not tested):

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class DateHourInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = tmpDateHour

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DateHourInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        hour_time1 = tmpHour.objects.get(pk=1)
        hour_time2 = tmpHour.objects.get(pk=2)             
        self.initial=[{'hour_time': hour_time1}, {'hour_time': hour_time2}]

class tmpDateHourInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = tmpDateHour
    formset = DateHourInlineFormSet
    extra = 1
```

Comment: thanks! I tried your code, but it just fills one time slot (if I have three time slots in tmpHour, only one of them will be returned).

Comment: @DingLi So it prefills one drop down but not the second one?